# FaceBook Native ads is not loading in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ads-api, native-ads

I am trying to implement Facebook native ads on my device. Test ads are working fine. However, production ads are not showing. It does displays an error showing

```
DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0,cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B89E486-EDF8-4E20-A7CE-CB60747C3E8B/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
```

and

```
DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 0 to 2, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9B89E486-EDF8-4E20-A7CE-CB60747C3E8B/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
```

What I did is loading the ads in viewdidLoad

```
func setupFacebookNativeAds()
{
    let nativeAd = FBNativeAd(placementID: Constants.adMob.FB_NATIVE_ID)
    nativeAd.delegate = self
    nativeAd.loadAd()
}
```

What will be the issue here?

Comment: do you get any error? the FBNativeAd delegate has a ad failed method, print the error message in there

Comment: @Scriptable the delegate method for error is not calling. that means the ads are working fine, right?

Comment: @Scriptable DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 0 to 2, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5BF9095D-5B37-49F0-ABD9-8893F19AD53F/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

what Does this have to do with the error?

Comment: yes, it probably just means that there wasn't an ad to show. i dont think that message that you have is an error, just a notification

Comment: @Scriptable, the test ads are working fine, whereas the production ads are not?... I mean the FBNativeAd delegate method not even calling?

Comment: have you ensured that loadAd is definitely being called and added breakpoints to all of the delegate methods? are you testing on an actual device?

Comment: Yup, testing on the device. And I'm just calling the above method **setupFacebookNativeAds()**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185362/discussion-between-faisal-and-scriptable).

Comment: sorry i am on a secure network and cannot access chat currently.

Comment: Oops, there was a mistake from my side, I used different delegate for the error...

Comment: Now after using the correct delegate, the error is printing like 

Error Domain=com.facebook.ads.sdk Code=1001 "No fill" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No fill, FBAdErrorDetailKey={ 
msg = "No fill"; 
}}

Comment: no fill means there were no ads to show

Comment: @Scriptable, hey I found some on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing. let me check that too

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adding new test devices in the Monetisation Manager. Get the IDFA for the ios devices and add new test devices. Now the Native Ads view is working.